# select same columns between two table on different join

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 2 tables like these:

[image: enter image de]

With this condition

```
ON dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Id = dbo.Joints.RightMaterialDescriptionId
AND dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Id = dbo.Joints.LeftMaterialDescriptionId
```

I want to select the itemcode of `RightMaterialDescriptionId` and `LeftMaterialDescriptionId` in my query. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to joins the  table twice with different aliases:

```
SELECT rmd.ItemCode as RightItemCode, lmd.ItemCode as LeftItemCode [, other columns...]
FROM dbo.Joints j
JOIN dbo.MaterialDescriptions rmd ON j.RightMaterialDescriptionId = rmd.Id
JOIN dbo.MaterialDescriptions lmd ON j.LeftMaterialDescriptionId = lmd.Id
```

**Note**: You might want to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`